# Azure DevOps When Work Items Meet Iterations

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a field that exposes WHEN a work item is assigned to its current iteration?
Seems like a pretty basic thing one might like to know, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know whether my anwser helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is **No** field that exposes when a work item is assigned to its iteration.

If you want to see this value, you can go to the page of the work item.

[image]

And then click "History". What you need to find is the record of the latest iteration update.
[image]

Of course, you can also get this value through the REST API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/updates
```

But just like getting it by website, you need to spend some time looking for this value, and you can't apply it to queries.

If you really need a field that exposes when a work item is assigned to its iteration. **You can create a new process that inherits from your current process and change the process of your project.** Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#prerequisites) for detailed steps.

And then, add a new field to show the latest updates of iteration. Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops#add-a-custom-field) for detailed steps.

This way you can treat the iteration change time as a real field. However, the defect is that when you make changes to an iteration, you need to manually change the value of this field.